# i have added update button inside datagridview how to change text on it when button is clicked in c#?

Tags: c#, text, datagridview

I am developing a windows application in c#. I have created a button inside datagridview using following code

```
  DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
  dataGridViewTrial.Columns.Add(btn);
  btn.HeaderText = "Update";
  btn.Name = "btn";
  btn.Text = "Update";
  btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

now i want to change the text of btn to "save" when the update button get clicked.Also i want to update my table.I m not getting it.Please help me:(

Comment: Do you want to change *all* buttons, or just one row? If just one row `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` isn't gonna work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistake you should do this

```
    //Here you add event to button
    void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is Button)
        {
            Button btn = e.Control as Button;
            btn.Click -= new EventHandler(btn_Click);
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        }
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is button)
            ((button)sender).Text = "new text";
    }
```

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Control is Button)
                {
                    Button btn = e.Control as Button;

                    // hook or unhook click event here
                }
            }
```